# Trying to filter the object passing to components reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I got the following code, I was trying to filter out "asia" object in my main object before I send to my components. But its not getting filtered.

```
let MainObject = [{property1: "asia", value:1},{property1: "US", value:2},{property1: "asia", value:3}]

let FilteringParameter =  ["asia", "EU"]

<Calendar
                        events={MainObject.filter(
                          itemX => !FilteringParameter.includes(itemX.property1)
                        )}
                      />
```

Comment: The keys in your objects are `propert1` (not `property1`)

Comment: oops maybe just a type when I post it, did some changes in my post

Comment: What is your expected output? @BillyPeralta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, could you not achieve this filtering by means of the following? In the case below, this would mean that the `events` would only include items from `MainObject` that have `property1: "asia"` key/value pairs:

#### Update:

If an empty array of filter parameters are supplied, the revised answer allow all items in `MainObject` to be returned in filtered result:

```js
 
const MainObject = [{property1: "asia", value:1},{property1: "US", value:2},{property1: "asia", value:3}];

function filterByParameters(parameters) {
  return MainObject.filter(itemX => parameters.length === 0 || parameters.find(parameter => parameter === itemX.property1))
}

var events = [];    

// With parameters
events = filterByParameters(["asia", "EU"]);
console.log('With parameters including "asia"', events);

// With no parameters
events = filterByParameters([]);
console.log('With no parameters', events);
```

Comment: Ill try this one out, I think this one solves it. Ill be back

Comment: @BillyPeralta ok , let me know how you get on :-)

Comment: Hi it seems its already working but you might have know a way to not filter anything when FilteringParameter is empty? when its its empty it should show all the item instead?

Comment: @BillyPeralta just updated answer - does this help you?

Comment: I think this one would work, let me just change my code. Ill be back